# ImportError: cannot import name 'DAG' from 'airflow' (unknown location)

Tags: python, airflow

I've installed the airflow on docker and i'm trying to create my first DAG, but when i use the command `FROM airflow import DAG` and try to execute it gives an import error. The file name isn't set as airflow.py to avoid import problems. Also i can't import the `from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator` it says that the `airflow.operators.python_operator` could not be resolved.

Here's the code that i've used to create my first DAG:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

default_args ={
    'owner': 'eike',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start-date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'email': ['eike@gmail.com.br'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 2,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=3),
}

dag = DAG(
    'anonimização',
    default_args = default_args,
    description = 'Realização da anonimzação do banco de dados propesq',
    schedule_interval = timedelta(None),
    catchup = False,
)
```

[Code of the DAG on vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JNYm.png)
[Airflow home page with DAG import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFyWI.png)

Comment: What version of Airflow do you have installed? Also the screenshots show two different errors. Which one is the one you wish to tackle?

Comment: I'm using airflow 2.3.0 and i want to first solve the problem from the first image where i can't import the DAG